# Strange bug with "edited" block in one question in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, questions

[Вводится целое число F. Найти число n, для которого значение n-ого числа Фибоначчи является ближайшим числу F, но не больше его. (на си) нужна помощь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1030500/15479).

> [image]

But it should be like this:

> [image]

**Firefox 69.0.1 (64-bit).**

**UPDATE:** you need to log in to reproduce.

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9553/15479.

Comment: What's expected here?

Comment: @john I've edited the question, to makes it clear.

Comment: If I recall... this may have been around the time when we _did_ make some changes to the menu markup, but they have since been reverted. The post looks normal to me in FF.

Comment: Thanks, @AdamLear. Yeah, for me it looks ok now too.

Comment: Also, @AdamLear is it related? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9567/15479

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Yeah, looks like it. I can't repro that now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the position?

It's one `div` getting shorter because of other `div` being too large.

"share edit close flag" (your second pic) is a lot shorter than six long words (your first pic). Makes the nesting `div` larger, in turn making the right `div` shorter, so the sub `div`s nested by it got rearranged as a vertical flow.

Comment: I've never experienced this bug before. So, probably, they changed something.

Comment: @Suvitruf It occasionally happens to me on smaller screens. It's annoying but natural.